# How to remove last ',' of a string?

Tags: php

I would like to remove last ',' of a string:

string is like that:

```
$str = a,b,c,d,e
```

the result should be:

```
$str = a,b,c,de
```

Comment: BTW, If you're building the string from an array, you can use `implode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a very short way is

```
$str  = "a,b,c,d,e";
echo substr_replace( $str, "", strrpos( $str, "," ), 1 );
```

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

strrpos — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string

Once you've found the position of the last `,` you can remove it e.g. with substring operations.

Answer (score 2):

you could do the following

```
$str = preg_replace(/,(.*)$/U, '$1', $str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). I am sure that you can devise a suitable regular expression for the match (summat like `,([^,])*$`) and a suitable replacement